# How to deal with dynamic columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a site that has different type of products with different specifications for each of them.

I want to be able to use only one products table with a set of columns but because columns are different depending on what type, I have to create multiple products table catering for each type. This I think is time consuming and not really effective way to manage as an ongoing solution.

Is there a good way to manage this type of scenario with the database?

I'm using Cakephp as the framework.

Comment: Please show your schema, or part of it, if possible

Comment: Consider using a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalise your data structure: for example, have a `product_info` table (with FK into the `products` table) that contains columns `key` and `value` to express additional information about each product.

Comment: @JohnKim: Yes, `product_info` would be a table of product metadata.  Whether it is the "best" way to go will depend on your requirements... but this is certainly one option that you can evaluate against the alternatives.

Comment: Ok then. Would this mean I need to store unique key values in another table for this meta table to reference when creating a new row or rows?

Comment: @JohnKim: No, just reference the PK of the `product` table.

Comment: OK. Does that mean key and values will depend on what's been posted from HTML form? In that case I might need to define this in the Model for validation purposes as the form inputs could be manipulated then changed in the meta table

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler lists three general approaches.

- [Single table](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) - Putting all the columns in one table and only using the ones you need (this sounds the closest to what you have)
- [Class table](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) - All classes have their own table storing data specific to that class (with the same primary key in every relevant table)
- [Concrete table](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) - The same as above, but only concrete classes have tables, not abstract ones.

Single table is the simplest unless you have a good reason not to - just have all possible fields there, and only use the ones you need in each class. You do have the disadvantage of not being able to enforce NOT NULL; if this matters, either make a custom constraint depending on the type of object, or use option 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about using the EAV model with cake a little while ago, I think this post might be helpful, but slightly outdated.
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2010/07/27/keyvalue-tables-and-how-to-use-them-in-cakephp-1-3/

Also, this could be very helpful for your particular question... Please take a look and study some concepts in [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) (a very popular PHP-based ecommerce framework) makes heavy use of EAV schemas and does a nice job of indexing and flattening the data.

You can certainly gain a lot of interesting perspective on EAV implementation. Whether you love it or not is a different story :)

Comment: Thanks for this. What does $this->alias stand for in Cake model?

Comment: In cake you can create an alias for the model i.e. User can be aliased to Shopper. (So it's a little "safer" to use the alias, just in case it was implemented in the model).